# Nestjs swagger form data through swagger module

Tags: nestjs

Is there any way to document form data type for controller?

I looked through documentation and was not able to find something suitable.

Using of @UploadedFile decorator didn't render anything in the documentation.

Any way to provide pure yaml string in this case to workaround this issue then?
Does xml filed in @ApiModelProperty decorator designed for this? Documentation on this topic is pretty poor and too verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this PR to get updated with the feature: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/87

Comment: Thanks for PR highlighting. I started discussion in another PR. Thought about helping implement it, but somebody already done it. Thanks again.